# How do i separate data from same month of different years?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to create a chart based on data from a table. On the chart, i want to show data from the last 12 months. By using the following code, my data on the current month will be combined with the data from the last years month. let say now its December, so I want to show the data from the last December including this December. How do I correct the query? Thank you for your help.

```
SELECT MONTH(InvoiceDate) AS 'Month', COUNT (DISTINCT InvoiceNo) AS 'Total Invoice' FROM SalesDetail WHERE InvoiceDate > (GETDATE() - 365) 
OR MONTH(InvoiceDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
AND YEAR(InvoiceDate) = (YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1)
GROUP BY MONTH(InvoiceDate)
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query uses non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Aside from a missing grouping, your query seems correct to me. I would like to point out, however, that if you are selecting data for example from "December 1st 2018" to "December 31st 2019" you will effectively be selecting 13 months rather than 12. I believe this could be on purpose... but if not, just be aware of it. Also, there's probably a dozen ways to write the same query, so I'd like to ask if you could write what you would expect as output from the query, in order to understand whether you want the result to present a list of date and numbers or just month and number and so on.

Comment: yes i want to show 13 months data. and i missed to include grouping by year as well. thanks for ur concern, i'll do better explanation next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT YEAR(InvoiceDate) AS 'Year', MONTH(InvoiceDate) AS 'Month', COUNT (DISTINCT InvoiceNo) AS 'Total Invoice' 
FROM SalesDetail 
WHERE (
  YEAR(InvoiceDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1 AND MONTH(InvoiceDate) >= MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
) OR (
  YEAR(InvoiceDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND MONTH(InvoiceDate) <= MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)
GROUP BY YEAR(InvoiceDate), MONTH(InvoiceDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may try below query -

```
SELECT MONTH(InvoiceDate) AS 'Month', COUNT (DISTINCT InvoiceNo) AS 'Total Invoice'
FROM SalesDetail
WHERE YEAR(InvoiceDate) = (YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1)
AND MONTH(InvoiceDate) >= MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY MONTH(InvoiceDate)
```

So basically just compare the past and current year and only month greater or equal to current year's month.